# How to save a row of data from database selected by a check box in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, checkbox

Here i have a query to my MySql database and I am taking out all the information about a course to be put in a row and displayed in my table. The last column of the table is a check box, that check box *I want to make it so it will save the row of data for each row that it is checked off*. The variable i chosen was `courses[]`, to be saved in array then saved in session to be accessed else where. I'm not sure how to extract the row data to put in to my array. Right now I have `value='$row2013` and that doesnt work because when I `var_dump($courses) = array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" [1]=> string(5) "Array" [2]=> string(5) "Array" [3]=> string(5) "Array" [4]=> string(5) "Array" }` , Which I have selected five courses.

To sum things up, I am not saving the right thing.

```
case 2013:
    $string2013 = "SELECT Course.CourseCode, Course.Title, Course.WeeklyHours, Semester.Term, Semester.SemesterCode
    FROM Course, CourseOffer, Semester WHERE Semester.YearNum='$selectedYear' AND Course.CourseCode=CourseOffer.CourseCode AND
    Semester.SemesterCode=CourseOffer.SemesterCode";
    if($Result2013 = mysqli_query($link, $string2013))
    {
        echo "<form action='CourseSelection.php' method='get'>
        <table><tr><th>Code</th><th>Course Title</th><th>Hours</th><th>Term</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
        while($row2013 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result2013))
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$row2013[CourseCode]</td><td>$row2013[Title]</td><td>$row2013[WeeklyHours]</td>
            <td>$row2013[Term]</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='courses[]' value='$row2013'></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>" + mysqli_error($link) + "</p>";
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to save only the row ID in the value of checkbox. This way you can easily recall a row from the database by its ID. `$row2013["CourseCode"]` should work.

When you do the POST request, you will get an array of IDs (`$_POST['courses']`). Of course you need to treat it as array, so you must iterate over it in order to get all the rows you selected.

If you `var_dump($_POST['courses'])` you should see something like this, assuming you have selected the first 5 rows:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=2)
  2 => string '3' (length=3)
  3 => string '4' (length=4)
  4 => string '5' (length=5)
```

Now just query the database according to the selected rows, and you're good to go:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Course
WHERE CourseCode = 1
   OR CourseCode = 2
   OR CourseCode = 3
   OR CourseCode = 4
   OR CourseCode = 5
```

Comment: This solution requires another call to the database, for information which is already in the table (via a previous SQL query) and that can easily be retrieved via POST instead.

Answer (score 1):

`value='$row2013'` ??? should be for example `value='$row2013["CourseCode"]'`

Comment: what if I want everything in that row? should i change to `mysqli_fetch_row` istead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: make it in a format that you can post, `value='$row2013'` is acting echo `$row2013` ... i don't think you have a profit doing `echo Array` which is printing the type of the Array and you will receive `value="Array"` -- but no t the contents ot the array

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with jQuery, which you could use to handle and validate your form also. Or, with each row, you could build an array for that row and pass it as a hidden value. Then when it posts, see that if the checkbox is checked, and if it is, have the script use the hidden value.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1:**
If I can assume that your Course table has one primary key column ('CourseCode') then you don't have to save the entire row as the value in a checkbox.  You only need to save the CourseCodes for the checked rows.  Then, you can add unique hidden inputs for each of the other table cells by appending the CourseCode to the input name, for example:

```
<input type='hidden' name='Title_" . $row['CourseCode'] . "' value='" . $row['Title'] . "'> etc.
```

In other words $_GET["courses"] will contain an array of CourseCodes which represents the rows which were clicked.  Then you can iterate over $_GET["courses"] and read the names of the other variables easily:

```
$lst_course_codes = !empty($_GET["courses"]) ? $_GET["courses"] : array();
foreach ($lst_course_codes as $code) {
    $title = $_GET["Title_$code"];
    etc...
}
```

**Way 2**: Store the checkbox values as json encoded strings: `json_encode($row2013)`
Then you can just iterate again (in CourseSelection.php):

```
foreach ($_GET["courses"] as $json) {
   $arr_row = json_decode($json, true);
   $title = $arr_row["Title"];
   etc...
}
```

I haven't checked closely for errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: in my input mark up, do I need to specify every column i want to save in my name and value?

Comment: For method 1, yes, if you want to retrieve that columns data in the script.

Comment: Also, I recommend you use POST, to avoid running into issues with data size limits.